# Using a dynamic list of checkboxes in a view, how to create the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an asp mvc 2 app lication where I want to display a list of check boxes that a user can select, based on a list of records in a database.  To display the list my model contains a List object and the view has a foreach, and outputs Html.CheckBox for each item in the list.

Is there a way to get the model populated with the selected checkboxes, given that the model can't have specific properties for each checkbox, because the list is dynamic?  Or do I have to manually iterate through the forms variables myself?

**Edit: Extra details as per sabanito's comment**
So in a simple view/model scenario, if my model had a property called Property1, then my view outputted a Textbox for Property1, when the form is posted via a submit button, the mvc framework will automatically populate a model with Property1 containing the text that was entered into the textbox and pass that model to the Controllers action.

Because I am dealing with a dynamic list of options the user could check, I can't write explicit boolean properties in my model and explicitly create the checkboxes in my view.  Given that my list is dynamic, I'm wondering if there are ways to create my model and view so that the mvc framework is able to populate the model correctly when the form is posted.

Comment: Could you please explain better what are you trying to do with the checkboxes once you have succesfully displayed them to the user. Is your problem in the Controller Method that receives the post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

Are you having any issues generating the checkbox's dynamically?

If not, create a property on your ViewModel that is a:

```
public List<string> CheckboxResults { get; set; }
```

When you generate your checkbox's in the view make sure they all share the name = "CheckboxResults". When MVC see's your ViewModel as a parameter on the action method it will automatically bind and put all the "CheckboxResults" results in the List (as well as your other ViewModel properties). Now you have a dynamic List based on which checkbox's your user checked that you can send to your DomainModel or wherever.

Pretty cool stuff. Let me know if you're having issues generating the checkbox's dynamically, that's kind of a seperate issue than model binding to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ViewModel that reflects your view exactly, and map your domain model(s) to the viewmodel.

At first it often seems appropriate to use domain models directly in the view, for no better reason than that they're simple to use.  However, as the view gets more complex over time, you end up putting a TON of conditional logic in your view, and end up with spaghetti.  To alleviate this, we typically create a ViewModel that correlates 1:1 with the view.

Comment: @LuckyLindy - I can't really do that, because the list of options is database driven, so I don't know at design time what the options will be

Comment: You can still do what I'm saying ... just add the source for the controls to an array/list in the viewmodel and the binder will handle it for you